# share data between the component built into the composition API and the component created with ​API options?

Tags: vue3

loader.load().then(() => {
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
input,
options
);

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(
      autocomplete,
      "place_changed",
      function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();            
        clear();`introducir el código aquí`            
        var detalles = place.address_components;
        data.value = getData(detalles);
        //emit data
        emit("getLocation", data.value);
       
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, [edit] tu pregunta y traduce a español que es el idioma de este sitio